# GPUImage simple code crash on execution

Tags: ios, gpuimage

This code crashes about 1 second after it is excuted (iOS7) :

```
-(void)initializeCamera
{
    GPUImageStillCamera *stillCamera=[[GPUImageStillCamera alloc]initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    stillCamera.outputImageOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    GPUImageView *image=[[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    GPUImageGrayscaleFilter *filter=[[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc]init];

    [self.view addSubview:image];
    [stillCamera addTarget:filter];
    [filter addTarget:image];
    [stillCamera startCameraCapture];
}
```

If it's any help just before crash a picture of what the camera captured is displayed.

GPUImage is installed with CocoaPod :

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GPUImage'
```

Comment: Start by updating your question with details of the crash. And point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: A *lot* can happen in "about 1 second" on a computer. Also, code doesn't crash *after* it is executed. It might *cause* a crash in some other code, but the code itself can't crash retroactively.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot I could plug the device to xcode to get these.

Comment: And you can run on the simulator. If it doesn't crash on the simulator, that'd be a useful thing to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not retaining your GPUImageStillCamera. You're creating it as a local instance within the `-initializeCamera` method and not holding on to it, so it will be deallocated the instant that `-initializeCamera` completes, causing a crash or other undefined behavior.

You need to hold on to this as a property or instance variable on the class that `-initializeCamera` resides within, or some other external strong reference.